# What could be the reason for ng-style not working for boolean in <td>?

Tags: angularjs

Tried the below markup:

```
  `<td ng-style="isTrue && {'background-color':'yellow'}">`
```

where I am trying to highlight in yellow if the cell value is true but the code is not working. What could be the cause?

Comment: There's no `ng-style` attribute in HTML. If you're using angular, tag your question as such.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that ng-style is an AngularJS attribute. You should do something like:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.isTrue = true;
});
```

```css
div[ng-style] {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='myctrl'>
  <div ng-style="{ 'background-color' : isTrue ? 'yellow' : 'red'}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using something similar that works.. <td ng-style="order.dmsPulseDispatched < 0 && {'background-color': 'pink'}">              but not working for boolean

Comment: Because ng-style has a model like this {'property': 'value'}. And in the way I did, isTrue ? 'yellow' : 'red' expression will return 'yellow' or 'red', based on isTrue value. Than 'background-color' will get expression's result.

Comment: Worked Thanks. I was just missing something